# VBA: Why won't code recognize the name of Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The scenario is that we have a vendor who sends us an Excel, which I want to import into an Access database.  In the first step, the user picks a file.  From that selection, the code looks for the sheets in the workbook, makes them into a dropdown on a form, and the user selects from one of those dropdowns (into the form) which sheet to upload.

Here’s where it gets problematic: I’m trying to get the last cell used on that sheet.  The code below fails at “Set wsobj” with a ‘subscript out of range error’.  When I copy and paste from the form and manually enter the sheet name in quotes (which should be the same data) the entire code works.  (The GetObject section works as well, and that uses a similar mechanism on taking the Workbook name from a variable on the form).   I’ve tried various things such as adding quote marks (both as strings and as character codes) but still does not work.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

```
Private Sub Command_Test_Click()

Dim xlobj
Dim wsobj
Dim rngobj

Set xlobj = GetObject(Me.Param_FileName)
Set wsobj = xlobj.worksheets(Me. Param_SheetName)
Set rngobj = wsobj.usedrange
MsgBox rngobj.Address

Set xlobj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try replace "Me" by "ActiveSheet" (I mean, the line with the sheetname)?

Comment: why is there a space in Me. Par ...

Comment: `Param_SheetName` is the control that holds the sheet name? You checked the content of the control with the debugger? `xlObj` is set to the correct workbook? You checked this with the debugger?

Comment: Should this be tagged with Access as well?

Comment: @Apostolos55: my bad about the space.  The code I pasted here had the hard copy entry I alluded to above.  The code that is messing up is "Set wsobj = xlobj.worksheets(Me.Param_Sheet)"

Comment: @FunThomas Not the debugger.  Since it's so short I just put in some MsgBoxes to show what parameters were being fed (and they are the correct workbook and sheet name).

Comment: @Dominique I messed around with Activating the workbook and sheet as you suggested.    Same result.  I really can't use "ActiveSheet" for the parameters, as the "Me" refers to the Access form not the Excel.  I could switch things up but I'd have to assume that the Excel has only a single sheet and I'd rather make as few assumptions as possible,